# Costmap obstacle layer plugin with Kinect for navigation

Tags: navigation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, is it possible to add kinect depth information for obstacle avoidance in navigation (i.e move_base) ? If so, how to do it?

Cheers,
Rickardo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220978/costmap-obstacle-layer-plugin-with-kinect-for-navigation/) by [Rickardo Leos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3712/rickardo-leos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Kinect information is usually integrated using the PointCloud2 data.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0